# Image.onload callback is firing inconsistently

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, lazy-loading, onload

I'm creating a lazy load function and I want to append the image to the DOM after it has successfully loaded to create a smooth transition.

I have a function which loops through a list of elements with a specific class, which gradually gets smaller every time you scroll.

Once an image in that list is considered "visible" I add a class and it no longer get's evaluated by the function.

I get the SRC by a data attribute, and create a new Image();

I do some css prop manipulation and add the src after I add the onload function.

This works around 1/3 of the time, most images never fire the onload callback and aren't added to the DOM.

My script is as follows:

```
var lazyClass = 'js-lazyload';

function lazyLoader() {

//Sets an elements var that checks how many non-visible elements still exist
// This variable is reset every time lazyLoader() is called
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + lazyClass + ':not(.js-lazyload--visible)');

//If there are no hidden elements left, end the function we don't need to proceed.
if (elements.length === 0) return;

//Loop through the elements array
//Only untoggled elements can be in this array because of the previous check
 for(var i = elements.length; i--;) {

    var lazyLoadElement = elements[i];

    if (
     lazyLoadElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight && 
     lazyLoadElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0 || 
     lazyLoadElement.getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight && 
     lazyLoadElement.getBoundingClientRect().top > 0) 
     {
     //The element was considered visible, let's go!
     lazyLoadElement.classList.add('js-lazyload--visible');

          var imgData = lazyLoadElement.getAttribute('data-image'),
                  image = new Image(),
                  lazyStyle = window.getComputedStyle(lazyLoadElement);

            if(lazyStyle.position !== 'relative'){
                if(lazyStyle.position !== 'absolute'){
                    lazyLoadElement.style.position = 'relative';
                }
            }

            image.onload = () => {
                lazyLoadElement.classList.add('js-lazyload--loaded');
                lazyLoadElement.insertBefore(image, lazyLoadElement.firstChild);
            }

            image.classList.add('js-lazyload__image')
            image.style.position = 'absolute';
            image.style.top = 0;
            image.style.left = 0;
            image.style.width = '100%';
            image.style.height = '100%';
            image.style.zIndex = '-1';
            image.style.objectFit = 'cover';
            image.src = imgData;


        }
    } 
}
```

Here is a fiddle which shows the issue:
Elements red - not visible
Elements blue - visible, but no image
Elements green - visible with loaded image

https://jsfiddle.net/dalecarslaw/yumv6rft/

No jQuery Please.

Comment: The issue is you declare a var for LazyLoadElement, which gets overwritten with every passage over the for loop. Then you use that value to set the image within your handler. This is a classical "var inside for loop" issue, but wrapped in a way to make it look complicated.

Comment: @Dellirium Could you create a working example with your explanation? https://jsfiddle.net/a46c5uhv/ this shows a working version, doing a check for image.complete

Comment: change the `var` to `let` inside the `for` loop, you got to change 6 letters of your code and your entire thing works. You declare `lazyLoadElement`,`image`, `lazyStyle` and `imgData` inside a for loop with a var, which has consequences, use `let` and it works as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/yumv6rft/96/

Comment: on a sidenote I've no idea how it manages to work with an image.complete check... shouldn't work from where im standing

Comment: If you create an answer, I will mark as accepted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onload callback that you added is in fact getting fired properly.
The issue in this particular case is the fact that the variables declared using `var` are function scoped. This means that as your `for` loop finishes it's iteration, the `lazyLoadElement` variable is pointing to the same element for all the handlers that get fired with an `onload` handler.

Changing the declarations for `lazyloadElement`, `imgData`, `image` and `lazyStyle` from `var` to `let` will make the code work as intended.